# Can't set airflow's celery_result_backend setting to 'rpc://'

Tags: python, celery, airflow

Is 'rpc://' a valid value for the 'celery_result_backend' setting in airflow config? It doesn't seem to work.

Assumed it works, as its a valid value in core celery config.

Comment: Celery supports multiple kinds of brokers; which kind are you using?
The backend needs to be paired with the broker.

Answer (score -1):

Since we're using Celery on Redis the URLs both start with: `redis://`.

If you were using Celery with RabbitMQ the URLs would start with: `amqp://`

The AWS SQS ones would start with: `sqs://`

I don't see any queue broker url that starts with `rpc://` in the [broker documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html).

I do see that the results backend for RabbitMQ could start with `rpc://` Since it's just a string passed to the library in question did you install with `celery[librabbitmq]` and you're not mixing up the two like I almost did?

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results